# Confused on how to solve $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1+mx)^n-(1+nx)^m}{x^2}$ and $\lim_{x\to 1} (\frac{m}{1-x^m}-\frac{n}{1-x^n})$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I'm having trouble solving these two problems using only elementary math. Find:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1+mx)^n-(1+nx)^m}{x^2}$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to 1} (\frac{m}{1-x^m}-\frac{n}{1-x^n})$$

My confusion may be due to the fact that I don't remember encountering these type of problems before. Do any of you recommend books that can help me improve my problem solving skills via elementary math or on different methods of problem solving (like the two I posted)?

Comment: Are you familiar with differentiation and L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: Yes I am but you can't use them. That's why I mentioned "using only elementary math." Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding the numerator by Binomial theorem, we get
\begin{align*}
(1+mx)^n-(1+nx)^m &= \left(1+ nmx + \binom{n}{2}m^2x^2 + \cdots \right) - \left(1+ mnx + \binom{m}{2}n^2x^2 + \cdots \right) \\
&= \frac{nm(n-m)}{2}x^2 + \cdots
\end{align*}
Hence the first limit is $\frac{nm(n-m)}{2}$

For the second limit, we need
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{m(1-x^n)-n(1-x^m)}{(1-x^n)(1-x^m)} &= \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{(1-x)(m(1+x+\cdots +x^{n-1}) - n(1+x+\cdots+x^{m-1}))}{(1-x)^2(1+x+\cdots+x^{m-1})(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})}\\
&= \lim_{x \rightarrow 1}  \frac{(m(1+x+\cdots +x^{n-1}) - n(1+x+\cdots+x^{m-1}))}{(1-x)(1+x+\cdots+x^{m-1})(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})}\\
&= \frac{1}{mn}\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}  \frac{(m(1+x+\cdots +x^{n-1}) - n(1+x+\cdots+x^{m-1}))}{(1-x)}\\
&= \frac{1}{mn}\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{m[(1-x)(-x^{n-2}-2x^{n-3} - \cdots - (n-1)) + n] - n[(1-x)(-x^{m-2}-2x^{m-3} - \cdots - (m-1)) + m]}{1-x} \\
&= \frac{1}{mn}\left[m\left(-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n\right) - n\left(-\frac{m(m-1)}{2}+m\right) \right]\\
&=\frac{m-n}{2}
\end{align*}
In the above, we have used this:
$$1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{n-1} = (1-x)(-x^{n-2}-2x^{n-3}-3x^{n-4} - \cdots - (n-2)x - (n-1)) + n $$
obtained by the usual division of $1+x+ \cdots +x^{n-1}$ by $1-x$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

You may suppose $m\ne n$. Use *Taylor's formula* at order $2$. The numerator becomes:
\begin{alignat}{2}
(1+mx)^n-(1+nx)^m&=\Bigl(1&&+nmx+\frac{n(n-1)}2m^2x^2+o(x^2)\Bigr)\\[-0.5ex]
&&& -\Bigl(1+mnx+\frac{m(m-1)}2n^2x^2+o(x^2)\Bigr)\\[1ex]
&=\rlap{\frac{mn(n-m)}2 x^2+o(x^2)}
\end{alignat}

Comment: The O.P wants elementary methods..not the taulor's formula

Comment: @MariosGretsas. The binomial theorem looks to be part of the elementary methods.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici...i just said because he mentioned Taylor's formula

Comment: Yes, binomial theorem is considered elementary math. Thanks for the responses. Is there any in depth books about solving problems using the binomial theorem?

Comment: Me personaly i like Bernard's answer..just the  mention of Taylor might confuce the O.P even if the answerer is applying just the binomial theorem..But what the hell,i'm a nice guy...;) +1)